# sending media file from android

Tags: android, media

i see this tutorial [Simple chat server client](http://towhidz.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/simple-chat-applicationclient-server-in-android/). this tutorial shows how to make a simple programming chat between android and server.

but i was wondering if this chat can send media file like .mp4 or .mp3? if it does, can anyone give me some tips of doing it? or perhaps if you have best reference for this kind of tutorial would give much help.

any related reference to send media preferable video (.3gp/.mp4/ etc) from android to server is really helpful. thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can modify that client so it opens a file as an InputStream and then reads from that InputStream and sends what it reads through the socket same as it currently does

Answer (score 0):

first of all need you files path and files name to send it so for more files sending you need uri list

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
```

now for fill the list

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkeditem.size(); i++) {
    File file = new File(path + "/" + checkeditem.get(i));          
    imageUris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
}
```

and using Intent with filed uri list  you can send media files using Bluetooth or more option

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUris);             
// shareIntent.setType("application/bluetooth");
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```